# Using clearInterval while setInterval runs

Tags: javascript, discord.js

Fairly new to using JS, and was trying to create a Discord bot that that takes a JSON array, randomly chooses 1 value from the correlating key, and automatically outputs it every 24 hours (basically a quote of the day bot).

I'm currently using `setInterval` to do this, however, I'm not able to `clearInterval` while it runs, leaving me to `ctrl + C` the PowerShell.

```
client.on('message', function(message) {

if(message.author.bot) return;

if(message.content.indexOf(config.prefix) !== 0) return;

const args = message.content.slice(config.prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/g);
const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

if (command === "qotd") 
{ 
const intervalSet = args.join(" ")
message.channel.send(randomQuestion())
    var interval = setInterval (function () 
    {
        //randomQuestion() is the function that returns the randomly selected value
        //message.channel.send(randomQuestion()) is there twice so it runs once 
        //before the timer starts (otherwise it'll take x time to output once
        message.channel.send(randomQuestion())
        .catch(console.error) // add error handling here
        return interval;
    }, intervalSet); 

}

if (command === "stopqotd")
{
    clearInterval(interval);
}
});
```

I have tried putting another command with `clearInterval(interval)` in the same `client.on()` and in a separate one, both don't stop it.

The ONLY reason it needs to stop is to add/remove quotes. Otherwise, it can just run endlessly.

Any suggestions?

Comment: So what would be the trigger to call `clearInterval()`?

Comment: if (command === "stopqotd")
 {
  clearInterval(interval);
 }

Comment: So how does `command` get passed to your script?

Comment: It's been edited to include the entire event

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `interval` variable is not in scope in the location you're trying to call `clearInterval()`.

To fix, move it to a higher scope:

```
let interval;

if (command === 'qotd') { 
  // ...
  interval = setInterval(function() {/*...*/}, intervalSet);
}

if (command === 'stopqotd') {
  clearInterval(interval);
}
```

This still puts you in a situation where, if you receive multiple `qotd` commands, you'll have multiple intervals running of which only the last will be stopped by the `stopqotd` command.

One way to address this would be to set the `interval` to `undefined` after you clear it, and test for that value when a `qotd` command is received.

```
let interval;

if (command === 'qotd') { 
  // ...
  if (!interval) {
    interval = setInterval(function() {/*...*/}, intervalSet);
  } else {
    message.channel.send('QOTD already running');
  }
}

if (command === 'stopqotd') {
  clearInterval(interval);
  interval = undefined;
}
```

Comment: I actually had JUST done seconds before I came back here. Thank you SO much for the help though!

Comment: `else {
    message.channel.send('QOTD already running');
  }` is brilliant though, and I hadn't thought of that. Thanks!!

Comment: You could do something similar for `stopqotd` to say `'QOTD is not running'`.